# How to customize the Release Cash Transactions mass release screen

Tags: acumatica, acumatica-kb

I am trying to customize the Release Cash Transactions screen and I am using this way to be able to call the Persist method, however when I release a record it does not enter the method specified above.

Here I am showing my code that if it works correctly for AP and AR.

I am doing the same for CA.

Could you help me that I'm wrong. Thanks for your help beforehand.

```
public class CAReleaseProcess_Extension : PXGraphExtension<CAReleaseProcess>
    {
        #region Custom

        private WeakReference<JournalEntry> je;
        public override void Initialize()
        {
            base.Initialize();
            PXGraph.InstanceCreated.AddHandler<JournalEntry>(delegate (JournalEntry graph)
            {
                je = new WeakReference<JournalEntry>(graph);
            });
        }

        public delegate void PersistDelegate();
        [PXOverride]
        public void Persist(PersistDelegate baseMethod)
        {
            CASplit doc = Base.CASplits.Current;
            ActualizarCATaxTran(doc);
            baseMethod();
        }

        public virtual void ActualizarCATaxTran(CASplit doc)
        {
            foreach (CATaxTran iTaxTran in Base.CATaxTran_TranType_RefNbr.Select(doc.AdjTranType, doc.AdjRefNbr))
            {
                if (iTaxTran != null)
                {
                    //do something

                }
            }
        }                  

        #endregion
    }
```

[CA502000](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UFcmw.png)

Comment: Hi Marco, 
Which version of Acumatica do you use? This should work in 2019R1

Comment: Hi Dmitry, Acumatica 2017 R2
Build 17,214.0044.

What happens is that our customers have that version.

Comment: In that version you can try to override something like CATaxTran_RowPersisting event

Comment: What should I do to make my code functions in the 2017 R2 version I am working on.

Comment: you can try to override CATaxTran_RowPersisting event instead of overriding the Persist method